# Mosquitto MQTT Broker performance on Docker

Tags: docker, mqtt, mosquitto, broker

Here are three scenarios that I tried while ingesting data into MQTT broker.

### Scenario 1

100 records per second with QoS=1, for a duration of 30 seconds from 3 machines (where each machine is a docker container) in parallel to a MQTT broker which is also a docker container.
So each machine is generating a total of 3000 messages over 30 seconds
Size of each message is 260 bytes.

Here is the receiver side data and below is the count of records received per machine.

```
JSON_DATE:MACHINE_NAME                COUNT(*)
"09166423-892a-4c84-9717-83b91ecbf2d5"  1,956
"b05eb890-ed0a-4272-aa95-7dce4f066cdb"  2,037
"e1ede903-f8f5-4bc8-95bb-ee286e6c00c3"  2,419
```

Inference : There is data loss for each machine

### Scenario 2

100 records per 5 seconds with QoS=1, for a duration of 30 seconds from 5 machines (where each machine is a docker container) in parallel to a MQTT broker which is also a docker container.
So each machine is generating a total of 3000 messages over 30 seconds
Size of each message is 260 bytes.

Here are two scenarios that I tried while ingesting data into MQTT broker.

```
JSON_DATE:MACHINE_NAME                 COUNT(*)
"043fc770-104c-4d0f-99e8-aae4a22bea60"  3,721
"06d39ec0-d799-43a9-9c58-16bbb67c0217"  3,085
"4374073b-6c75-4788-b1f7-bcd65aa755aa"  3,587
"675467d5-4361-4a61-becf-0a20fc5ad84f"  3,500
"825d3880-99db-425b-b867-3254fef394f3"  3,495
```

Inference : There is no data loss for any machine. There are multiple deliveries for most of the machines

### Scenario 3

100 records per 5 seconds with QoS=1, for a duration of 30 seconds from 10 machines (where each machine is a docker container) in parallel to a MQTT broker which is also a docker container.
So each machine is generating a total of 3000 messages over 30 seconds
Size of each message is 260 bytes.

Here are two scenarios that I tried while ingesting data into MQTT broker.

```
JSON_DATE:MACHINE_NAME                 COUNT(*)
"06e08aeb-f258-40eb-adcd-efe1b2e3725e"  3,162
"0be5975c-b364-450e-b550-62834d32a18f"  3,181
"30f6cea9-efde-42b5-bcb2-b81e360d27b4"  2,959
"500465c1-7ff0-4097-a0d7-d22b55b73079"  3,142
"ac61be0c-ac40-44fd-930c-10b01d98aa4a"  3,235
"b259f4cd-cd69-4582-b428-53192ac5d13e"  3,027
"b8567bf2-cdc8-4907-8c03-7bbe78d36cb8"  3,212
"ca3bda96-4b60-4d97-a88a-22b10d500650"  2,932
"d6bb5650-1fdb-45cf-9bfc-a979594aba0f"  3,287
"dff45255-b48e-45a9-9e71-a7cfd9559139"  3,069
```

Inference : There is minor data loss for some machines

Below is the screen shot of the docker stats when scenario 2 was in execution.

[image]

```
##Publisher Code. This is run within a docker container

import paho.mqtt.client as paho 
from paho import mqtt
from random import randrange, uniform
import time
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process
from os import getpid
import os
import random
import datetime
import os
import uuid



def task():
    pid = getpid()
    machine_name =  str(uuid.uuid4())
    topic_name =  machine_name
    print("{0} : {1}".format(machine_name, topic_name))

    for i in range(30) :

        mqttBroker ="localhost" 
        client = paho.Client("Temperature_Inside")
        client.connect(mqttBroker,1883)
        client.loop_start()

        for _ in range(100):
            sensor_reading = str(random.uniform(10, 12))
            ingest_time = str(datetime.datetime.now())
            sensor_payload = "{ 'Topic_Name': \'" + topic_name + "\', 'Msg_Id': \'" + str(i)+ '-'+ str(_) + "\', 'Ingestion_Time': \'" + ingest_time + "\', 'Machine_Name': \'" + machine_name + "\','Reading': \'"+ sensor_reading +"\' }"
            print(sensor_payload)
            client.publish(topic_name,sensor_payload,qos=1)
            
        sleep(5)



# entry point
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sleep(1)

    task()
```

```
## Code to trigger the docker container

from multiprocessing import Process
import os
import subprocess
import docker
import sys


def task():
    client = docker.from_env()
    container = client.containers.run('datagen', detach=True,network="host",auto_remove=True)
    print(container.logs())



# entry point
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    print("Number of threads to start : {0}".format(sys.argv[1]))

    n=int(sys.argv[1])
    for i in range(n):
        process = Process(target=task)
        process.start()
```

```
##Finally here the subscriber code

import paho.mqtt.client as paho 
from paho import mqtt
import time

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    print("received message: " ,str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))
    with open('files_sub/data_recv.txt','a+') as f:
         f.write("Message received: "  + str(message.payload) + "\n")

mqttBroker ="localhost"
client = paho.Client("Smartphone")
client.connect(mqttBroker,1883) 

client.loop_start()

client.subscribe("#",qos=1)
client.on_message=on_message 

time.sleep(300)
client.loop_stop()
```

Here is what I am looking for.

Is there a threshold that we can use as a benchmark for MQTT broker running on a docker ?
Is there a way that we can improve the performance ?

Comment: As it is this question is unanswerable, we know nothing of the testing methodology or the hardware. If it's all running on the same virtual docker network there shouldn't be any TCP packet loss and even if there was there should be retransmission so no message loss.

Comment: I have shared the publisher and subscriber code in case you want to replicate the scenario.

Comment: If you have three clients, publishing as fast as they can, and a single subscriber, then it's likely the subscriber will fall behind (possibility limited by broker settings like `max_inflight_messages`, with `max_queued_messages` leading to dropped messages). Please share your Mosquitto configuration (ideally share everything required to duplicate your experiment).

Comment: @Brits Thanks for sharing this information. I am using all the default settings. I am not playing around with any of the config parameters.

Comment: @Ritab you probably need to update the settings - `max_inflight_messages` defaults to `20`; set this to `0` and rerun your test.

Comment: @Brits I have tried using the advised parameters in the config file. However for my setup, no performance parameter settings gave the better results. All other settings are increasing the data loss in the target. Pasting the list of parameters that gave the best result with minimal data loss.


listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log
autosave_interval 10
# max_inflight_bytes 0
# max_inflight_messages 0
# max_queued_bytes 0
# max_queued_messages 50000

Comment: Please edit the question when adding info (very hard to read in the comments). In that `conf` file the relevant lines appear to be commented out... Looking at your code I'm guessing the issue is `paho.Client("Temperature_Inside")` (you have multiple publishers connecting with the same client ID - they will fight to maintain a connection; see [MQTT-3.1.4-2](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718032))